# setOnItemClickListener on ListView not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

I am having some difficulties in managing `onItemClickListener` in my Fragment view. When I press on items in list, nothing happens. Please check my code and let me know if I am doing it right or is there anything wrong with my code.

```
public class People extends BaseFragment implements OnClickListener {
    static String name;
    ListView listview;
    TextView et;
    static public List<SuccessStoreyItem> success_list3 = new ArrayList<SuccessStoreyItem>();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.home,null);
        ParserResult pr = new ParserResult();
        Button b=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.home1);
        listview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_home);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ullu ka patha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /*Profile frg3 = new Profile();
                Bundle b3 = new Bundle();
                String username = success_list3.get(position).getStorey_id();
                b3.putString("username", username);
                frg3.setArguments(b3);
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).launchNewFragment(frg3, R.id.tab2);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Name :"+name ,1).show();*/
            }
        });

        et=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        if(ParserResult.success_list2.size() != 0){
            success_list3 = ParserResult.success_list2;
        }
        listview.setAdapter(new Adapters(success_list3 ,MainActivity.mainactivity_context));
        ParserResult.success_list2 = new ArrayList<SuccessStoreyItem>();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        setTitle(R.string.Home);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        name=et.getText().toString();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Name", name);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Name :"+name ,1).show();


        //((MainActivity)getActivity()).launchNewFragment(new Home2(),R.id.tab1);
    }


}
```

**UPDATES:**  List view structure added

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_tv_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view_imageview"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view_tv_age"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_tv_age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view_tv_username"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view_imageview"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:src="@drawable/chevron" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**FRAGMENT LAYOUT**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10sp" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="New Machtes"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/iconnew"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="16" />
</RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in make toast try changing getActivity() to getApplicationContext()

Comment: post listitem layout and Adapters

Comment: code updated .. please check

Comment: is there some log error message that you could post here?

Comment: no there is no error message or warning message in log.

Comment: Try adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your `<RelativeLayout..` in the ListView item layout.

Comment: @rogcg thank you so much, it worked. can you please explain me what was the problem here. PS: you can add answer i will accept it

Comment: Here is explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312197/onitemlongclicklistener-is-not-working-in-a-custom-listview/18312410#18312410

Comment: @FaisalAshraf if it worked for you please set as correct answer. =)

Comment: @rogcg do u know about its related third party library.

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your `<RelativeLayout..` in the ListView item layout.

#### A possible explanation

Looking into your listview item layout, I see you have an `ImageButton`. It happens that `ImageButton` *steals* the focus from the view group (the list row) it is in. This means that when you click the list row, it is always the `ImageButton` that captures the event.

By adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` we block the list row descendants from stealing the focusability.

You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability).

Answer (score 0):

i think your listview.setadapter() line and the data associated with it, should come before you set onclickitemlistener() to that listview..

Comment: just did it, but nothing happens